# Google cloud platform for unity games

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-speech, video-intelligence-api

I am planning to use Google Cloud Platform features like Cloud Speech-to-Text, Cloud Text-to-Speech, Cloud Video Intelligence, Cloud Sentiment Analysis, and Cloud Vision in my unity games. Is there any UNITY SDK available for the above mentioned features.

If not what is the other way to use the above mentioned functions in my Unity games?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to Unity, you can look at the following [list of integration tools](https://assetstore.unity.com/categories/tools/integration/?order_by=relevance&q=category%3A102&q=google&q=cloud&rows=42&sc=tools%2Fintegration) related to Google Cloud products.

If you are not willing to purchase them or want to come up with your own solution, you can make [API calls](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/overview) to the desired Google Cloud services.

Its is also possible to use C# client libraries for [Google Cloud Video Intelligence](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp),  [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp), [Google Cloud Natural Language](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Language.V1/index.html),  [Google Cloud Speech-to-Text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp) (there is no C# client library for Google Cloud Text-to-Speech yet, therefore [API calls](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/apis) are the only option right now).

Answer (score 0):

you can also look at this assets: [Frostweep Games - Google Cloud Machine Learning Plugins](https://assetstore.unity.com/lists/google-cloud-machine-learning-108078)

Comment: this should be in comment